# Is it ok to work directly on the data in req.body?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on an app in Node/Express/Jade.

I have a GET route which render a form. When the user submit this, a POST route is handling the request. I use bodyParser, which populate the req.body.

I then sanitize, validate and generate new data **directly** in the req.body:

```
// Shorthand variable
var doc = req.body;

// Sanitise and transform user input
doc.company = sanitize( doc.company ).trim();
doc.contact_person = sanitize( doc.contact_person ).trim();
...

// Validate user input
validator.check( doc.company, 'Some error message' ).notEmpty();
validator.check( doc.contact_person, 'Another error message' ).notEmpty();
...

// Generate new object data
doc.slug = sanitize( doc.company ).toSlug();
...
```

**Question:** is if there are any special reason for me **not** to edit the data directly in the req.body? Should I instead making a new "doc" object from the data in req.body, and in that new object sanitize, validate and add the new generated data.

Comment: I typically do what your code does above, assign the body to a var, modify there. Although I have modified the `req.body` and didn't see any hazardous results, so thats a plus!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine to edit data in `req.body`. The only thing you should be aware of is that the next route or middleware will get a modified version of `req.body`.

So, you may create a single route/middleware to sanitize and transform your `req.body` and then use transformed results in multiple routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely modify it.  For example, the `express.json` middleware parses raw body data into JSON for the rest of the middleware chain.

It's best to use a copy if your intention isn't to alter data for the rest of the chain, even if it won't interfere with correct operation.  It prevents sometimes hard-to-debug errors that might crop up in later development.